# google webmaster is crawling both file urls

Tags: url, web-crawlers, googlebot

webmaster is crawling both the urls, one which is `SEO friendly` and the one `.php` urls for the same page thus showing duplicate title and description for those pages.

urls of .php were changed through .htaccess file. what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) from the `.php` URLs to the rewritten URLs. If that is not possible for some reason you need to add a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to the `.php` URL pointing to the rewritten URL.